# Set multiset добавление элементов

Tags: c++, set, multiset

Можно ли добавить элемент в начало сета или нет? Единственное что нашел это mySet.insert, но она добавляет его в соответствии с ключом.

Comment: Конечно, только в соответствии с ключом. Как бы иначе он мог так быстро работать? :)

Comment: В этом и смысл multiset - поддерживать сортировку. Если вам нужно что-то добавить в начало, значит вам нужен другой контейнер (vector, deque)

Comment: @Harry в том то и дело что мне нужно поставить элемент в самое начало перед корневым, но похоже что это невозможно

Comment: Тогда используйте для этого что-то другое...